# Change on page _load "og:image" meta tag asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, meta-tags

I want to change og:image property on page_load.

this is my current code:

```
HtmlMeta tag2 = new HtmlMeta();
tag2.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");
tag2.Content = "test";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag2);
```

this is the error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure header in your page markup has `runat="server"` :

```
<head runat="server">
```

Comment: i have runat="server" but i am having The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).